# What exactly are WENO schemes and where are they used?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, weno

I am currently trying to understand what WENO schemes are and most of the literature on web talks about cell-face reconstruction. What I am unable to understand is the origin of these discontinuities at the cell-faces. Can anyone explain where exactly does a WENO scheme come into picture and why is it used?

Answer (score 4):

> In numerical solution of differential equations, WENO (weighted essentially non-oscillatory) methods are classes of high-resolution schemes. WENO are used in the numerical solution of hyperbolic partial differential equations.

as you can find in the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WENO_methods). The derivation of the weno scheme can be found in [the original article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999184711879?via%3Dihub).
The fact that they are used near discontinuities is because, usually, finite volume (but also finite elements) schemes, in proximity of the discontinuity present spurious oscillation, also known [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon). For this reason, usually. near the discontinuities you need to use very refined cells and with linear schemes you can achieve only 1st order accuracy to obtain a non-oscillatory behaviour (have a look at [this link](https://www.brown.edu/research/projects/scientific-computing/sites/brown.edu.research.projects.scientific-computing/files/uploads/Essentially%20non-oscillatory%20and%20weighted.pdf)). To obtain non-oscillatory schemes with higher than first order accuracy, one must consider nonlinear schemes. In this sense the [TVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_diminishing) schemes revolutioned the fluid mechanics but still they have a drawback: they have degeneracy of accuracy to first order near smooth extrema. For this reason the ENO and WENO schemes were introduced.
For what it concerns the discontinuities they can appear:

- in monophase flows in case of shock waves (you can think at it in case of the whole domain or on a single discretized cell)
- in multiphase flow in case of discontinuity between the two phases (in this case you can have a look at the chapter 2 [here](https://www.theses.fr/2021NORMR012), where are explained the different possible formulations of multiphase flow.